# How can I generate a react app as a multi-page static site?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm working on a multi-page site in React.js and using react router's `hashHistory` for the different pages. My problem is that I want to remove the hash symbol in the URLs and I want to keep the site static so this is why I'm not using `browserHistory`. Is there a way for me to convert the React app into a static site where each of my react router routes becomes it's own html file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Webpack, you can an [entrypoint](https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html) for each route. You can generate HTML files with the [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) using the [multiple html files](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#generating-multiple-html-files) option and [filter chunks](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#filtering-chunks) to load different JS assets for each page.

However, if you have shared states between the pages, you'll have to come up with a strategy for them to communicate (maybe localstorage). This is one of the problems that single-page apps solve with client-side routes.